# If $p$ is a Sophie Germain prime, that is $q = 2p+1$ is also prime and $a\not\equiv \pm1$(mod $p$) then $a^2 \not\equiv 1$(mod $q$).

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, legendre-symbol

I am trying to understand the proof that

If $p$ is a Sophie Germain prime, that is $q = 2p+1$ is also prime and $a\not\equiv 0,\pm1$(mod $p$)
$$\text{If }\biggl(\frac{a}{q}\biggr)=-1 \text{ then }a \text{ is a primitive root mod(q)}$$

where $\bigl(\frac{a}{q}\bigr)$ is **Legendre's symbol**

Since $a^{q-1} \equiv 1$ (mod $q$) and $q-1 = 2p$, $\operatorname{ord}_q(a) = \{1,2,p,2p\}$

Since $(\frac{a}{q})=-1$, we got $\operatorname{ord}_q(a) \neq1,p$

So, there remains to show $a^2 \not\equiv 1\pmod q$.

Comment: With "$a\not\equiv 0,\pm1$(mod $p$)", should the $p$ be $q$ instead? As it's stated now, this doesn't make much sense since, due to there not being any limitation on the size of $a$, the condition doesn't actually restrict anything about what $a$ may be modulo $q$. Also, if that condition is mod $q$, then you can show $a^2 \not\equiv 1 \pmod{q}$ since $a^2 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{q} \; \to \; (a - 1)(a + 1) \equiv 0 \pmod{q}$. With $q$ being prime, then $q \mid a - 1 \; \to \; a \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$ or $q \mid a + 1 \; \to \; a \equiv -1 \pmod{q}$, with neither situation being allowed.

Comment: In the text just say $a$ not congruence to 0,±1 modulo p. So, I think this will be working as well

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work as well. I'm quite certain it's a typo in the text. As currently stated, there are no $a$ for $p = 2$ or $p = 3$. However, for *every* prime $p \ge 5$, note $a = 3q - 1 = 6p + 2$ is a counter-example, which I'll leave to you to prove. You may wish to check if there's a correction available, e.g., if the "text" is from a book then, if you haven't already done so, I suggest checking online for any errata for that book.